# Mostrar Registros agrupados en vista blade

Tags: laravel

Como estan buenas tardes, Tengo en mi controlador una funcion que me devuelve agrupados los registros de una query:

Ahora bien, obtengo el resultado de la consulta y l oenvio via compact a mi vista donde debo generar una tabla principal y dentro cada uno de los items correspondientes a un numero de ot pero como se ven en la imagen, me genera 3 tablas en lugar de dos jeje

El codigo de la funcion en el controllador la tengo asi:

```
  $retiros = DB::table('retiro_mat_despachos as retiro')
        ->join('det_despachos as detDespacho' , 'detDespacho.id' ,'retiro.despacho_id')
        ->join('despachos as despacho','despacho.id','detDespacho.despacho_id')
        ->join('det_retiro_mat_despachos as detalle' , 'detalle.retiro_mat_despacho_id' , 'retiro.id')
        ->join('users as usuario' , 'usuario.id' ,'retiro.user_id')
        ->join('bodegas as bodega' , 'bodega.id' , 'retiro.bodega_id')
        ->select('retiro.id as id_retiro','detalle.retiro_mat_despacho_id','despacho.num_ot', 'retiro.fecha_retiro', 'retiro.status', 'retiro.despacho_id as id_despacho',
        'detalle.id as id_detalle', 'detalle.articulo', 'detalle.modelo', 'detalle.marca', 'detalle.mac',
         'detalle.serie', 'detalle.observaciones', 'detDespacho.tecnico_id','usuario.name',
         'bodega.nombre_bodega')
        /* ->where('retiro.despacho_id' , 4) */
        ->where('detDespacho.tecnico_id' ,$tecnico_id)
       /* ->groupBy('despacho.id') */
        ->get();

        //$datos = collect($retiros)->groupBy('despacho.num_ot');

        /* $as= det_retiro_mat_despacho::all();

        $ase = $as->groupBy('retiro_mat_despacho_id'); */

         $datos = [

            //'todos' => $retiros
            'todos' => $retiros->groupBy('retiro_mat_despacho_id')
        ];

        dd($datos) ;

        return view('logistica.despacho.reversa.indexTecnico', compact('despacho','retiros'));
```

Ahora haciendo unos cambios obtengo el array como deberia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no puedo generar las 2 tablas con sus items correspondientes (me genera tres tablas):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

eL CODIGO EN LA VISTA es este:

```
 <!--TABLA MATERIALES RETIRADOS -->
                @foreach ($retiros as $retiro)
                <div class="card col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <strong class="text-secondary">DESPACHO OT N°  {{$retiro->num_ot}}</strong>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="alert alert-success" style="display:none">
                            {{ Session::get('success') }}
                        </div>

                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Fecha Retiro</th>
                              <th>Bodega Destino</th>
                              <th>Material/Producto</th>
                              <th>Marca</th>
                              <th>Modelo</th>
                              <th>Serie 1</th>
                              <th>Serie 2</th>
                              <th>Reversa</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <tr>
                                  <td>{{$retiro->fecha_retiro}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$retiro->nombre_bodega}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$retiro->articulo}}</td>
                              {{--     <td>{{$retiro->marca}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$retiro->modelo}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$retiro->mac}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$retiro->serie}}</td> --}}
                                  <td>
                               {{--        @if ($retiro->status == 0)
 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnEntregarTbl" data-target="#modal-reversa-{{$retiro->id_retiro}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-id="{{$retiro->id_retiro}}" data-despacho="{{$retiro->id_despacho}}" data-retiro="{{$retiro->id_retiro}}" data-material="{{$retiro->articulo}}" title="Recepcionar Material">ENTREGAR</button>
 @else
                                      <span class="badge badge-success">ENTREGADO</span>
                                      @endif --}}
                                  </td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la función groupBy de collections una vez que hayas obtenido la consulta

```
$retiros = $retiros->groupBy('retiro_mat_despacho_id');
```

En tu código blade, tratalo de la siguiente manera

```
@foreach ($retiros as $retiro)
     <div class="card col-lg-12">
         <div class="card-header">
             <strong class="text-secondary">DESPACHO OT N°  {{$retiro[0]->num_ot}}</strong>
         </div>

         <div class="card-body">
             <div class="alert alert-success" style="display:none">
                 {{ Session::get('success') }}
             </div>

             <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                 <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th>Fecha Retiro</th>
                         <th>Bodega Destino</th>
                         <th>Material/Producto</th>
                         <th>Marca</th>
                         <th>Modelo</th>
                         <th>Serie 1</th>
                         <th>Serie 2</th>
                         <th>Reversa</th>
                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                     @foreach($retiro as $item)
                         <tr>
                             <td>{{$item->fecha_retiro}}</td>
                             <td>{{$item->nombre_bodega}}</td>
                             <td>{{$item->articulo}}</td>
                             {{--<td>{{$item->marca}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$item->modelo}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$item->mac}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$item->serie}}</td> --}}
                                  <td>
                               {{--        @if ($item->status == 0)
 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnEntregarTbl" data-target="#modal-reversa-{{$item->id_retiro}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-id="{{$item->id_retiro}}" data-despacho="{{$item->id_despacho}}" data-retiro="{{$item->id_retiro}}" data-material="{{$item->articulo}}" title="Recepcionar Material">ENTREGAR</button>
 @else
                                      <span class="badge badge-success">ENTREGADO</span>
                                      @endif --}}
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach

                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

Comment: Hola, hice el cambio pero al parecer tampoco esta haciendo bien la agrupacion ya que deberia hacer: id_despacho 5: {}, id_despacho->4 {}{}

Comment: Has un dump o dd para ver que tipo de dato estas obteniendo

Comment: obtengo una coleccion con un array segun la imagen

Comment: Agrega tu código de blade

Comment: añadido el codigo de la vista

Comment: Intenta con mi respuesta editada